# DAX PowerBi - Multiplication in a measure gives a wrong sum in the total-row of a table-visualization

Tags: powerbi, dax, multiplication, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have two tables, "stock" and "prices". In table "stock" I made a calculated column in the DAX-editor (called "Voorraad").

```
Voorraad = CALCULATE (COUNT(stock[EAN]), stock[Locatie] IN {"magazijn", "ontvangst"})
```

The two tables are related on "EAN", **a many-to-many relationship**.

[image]

The visualization in PowerBi shows a right outcome for the column "Voorraad". Then I also wanted to add a column in the visualization with "stockvalue", which shows me the multiplication of "Voorraad" by "Inkoop".

[image]

This is working out by a measure named "stockvalue" in table "stock":

```
stockvalue = SUM(stock[Voorraad])* SUM('prices'[inkoop])
```

Per row this works fine. But putting it in a table-visualization the total row also shows the multiplication of the total-voorraad * the total-inkoop.
So this gives (in my example) the output of 379 * € 88,35 = € 33484,65
Which obviously should be **€ 3133,00**

**Anyone knowing the right thing to get this working?**

Comment: I changed the measure to a new column in table "stock". Then I used this code to add another column to table "stock":
`stockvalue = SUM(stock[Voorraad])* SUM('prices'[inkoop])`
So far so good. Unfortunately on the Total-row it also shows the product of: total "voorraad" * total "inkoop"
This of course is not what I need to happen. I want the total of "stockvalue" to show up.

Comment: From [Multiply 2 columns by row then get the sum](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Multiply-2-columns-by-row-then-get-the-sum/td-p/801746), applied to your question:

`stockvalue = stock[Voorraad]*LOOKUPVALUE(prices[inkoop], stock[EAN], prices[EAN])`

Comment: When I add a column to table "stock" with this DAX-code it doesn't seem to work. An error message shows up saying the column stock[EAN] doesn't excist  or doesn't have a relation with a table in the present context. Simultaniously my other calculated column 'voorraad' gets an error sign with an exclamation mark in it.
I'm adding this column in the main powerbi-desktop window on the left side, clicking on the table and then adding a column.

Comment: Basicly the `stockvalue = SUM(stock[Voorraad])* SUM('prices'[inkoop])` is working, accept for the total-row. There is also the product shown for total "voorraad" * total "inkoop".

Comment: @Lorenz: could this error appear because of the other calculated column in the same table "stock"?

Comment: Create a measure that is only there to sum the whole column of the stock table where you add the stockvalue: `total_stockvalue = SUM(stock[stockvalue])`. That is taken from [How to add total sum of each rows within group with DAX Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442173/how-to-add-total-sum-of-each-rows-within-group-with-dax-power-bi). Hide the current total of stock table and add that measure instead. Not sure if that helps, I do not have Power BI installed, and it is quite long ago that I have used it. I cannot help with other questions.

Comment: The last comment didn't give me the solution I needed (or at least I didn't get it working.
I edited my question, to have it more accurate to the situation I'm in now.

Comment: Yes that is the right workflow. Getting a measure of a measure should not be an issue. I do not know how to go on, hopefully someone else will go on:) Perhaps you better search the internet and try answering yourself, sometimes such questions here are just not answered since they often are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is found in: [Measure Totals, The Final Word](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Quick-Measures-Gallery/Measure-Totals-The-Final-Word/m-p/547907)

I put in one measure in table "stock"

```
stockvalue_onerow = SUM(stock[voorraad])*SUM(prices[inkoop])
```

Then I put in another measure in table "stock"

```
    Stockvalue = 
VAR __table = SUMMARIZE(stock, [id], "__value",[stockvalue_onerow])
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE(stock[id]),[stockvalue_onerow],SUMX(__table,[__value]))
```

**This last one is to be used in the table-visualization! Problem solved!**